# Each of the logins should have displayed data based on different WHERE- how i need change code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need a help. What should I use in SQL based on the login [select SUBSTRING (SUSER_NAME (), 13.10] to display a different table content based on WHERE?

**Each of the logins should have displayed data based on other WHERE.**

I try with this code but I still have a problem

```
select *,
case when t1.login = (select SUBSTRING (SUSER_NAME (), 13,10) then (select pok from t1 where pok = @pok) else 'N' end as result
from t1
```

**EDIT:**

I created a report in SSRS - data is displayed depending on the logged in user. Everything is played here. However, for the regional directors in their report, I need to create a new table with a summary of their sellers in the region.

Existing table
table1

```
| DATA   | SALES  | PROFIT | EXPRENSE | PROFIABILITY | REGION |
|--------|--------|--------|----------|--------------|--------|
| 201901 | Sales1 | 50     | 50       | 0            | A      |
| 201901 | Sales2 | 100    | 50       | 50           | A      |
| 201901 | Sales3 | 105    | 55       | 50           | B      |
| 201901 | Sales4 | 90     | 80       | 10           | C      |
| 201901 | Sales5 | 190    | 80       | 110          | A      |
```

A report is created for each individual on the login basis, but for Sales5 it is necessary to create a Sales1 report due to the fact that they work in the same region and Sales5 is its director.

The individual report code is as follows:

```
select * from t1
WHERE
data in (@data_raportu)

 AND
t1.sales in (
SELECT distinct [sales]
       FROM [test]. [Dbo]. [T2]
where [login_sales] in (@sales_filtr))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, instead of how you are trying to do it?

Comment: The given query is not appropriate bcoz sub query can return multiple values. Explain your question little bit more specifically.

Comment: have I explained more now ?

Comment: Aleksander, it seems you need either an additional level of data to indicate managers or directors and who reports to them (Standard normalization) or, if you want fewer entities then you need a 1 to many table where a single login ID can 'access' 1 or more sales areas.

Comment: it's true @craig.white I created additional tables with the directors and created the following query
```select * from t1
WHERE 
data in (@data_raportu)
 AND 
t1.sales in (
SELECT distinct [sales]
       FROM t3
       where [login] in (@sales_filtr) )

union all 

select * from t1
WHERE 
t1.region= ( select distinct region from t1 where t1.sales in (
SELECT distinct [sales]
       FROM t3
       where [login] in (@sales_filtr)))```

Comment: Well, not exactly how I was envisioning it, but if your data in t3 is configured correctly it should be okay.  Unfortunately your data example is incomplete so we are unable to offer more specific ideas, but if you have what you need, then no worries.  If not, please post sample data for t2 and t3 so we can offer more specifics.  Thanks!